# Check Password on MySql

Tags: mysql

I'm new on MySql,

Problem:

```
CREATE TABLE Empleado (
    Usuario varchar(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK(LEN([Usuario]) = 10),
    Contraseña varchar(7) NOT NULL CHECK (
        LEN([Contraseña]) = 7 AND
        [Contraseña] LIKE '%[0-9]%[0-9]%' AND                                -- 2 numbers
        [Contraseña] LIKE '%[A-Za-z]%[A-Za-z]%[A-Za-z]%[A-Za-z]%[A-Za-z]%')  -- 5 letters
    )
);
```

**IN SQL SERVER** you can use LEN but in **MYSQL** what I must use?

Comment: SQL server and MySQL are different.

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE but is possible use check in mysql?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, MySQL has [CHECK CONTRAINTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html).

You are however storing clear text passwords. This is strongly discouraged.

Recommend using [password_hash](https://code-boxx.com/password-encrypt-decrypt-php/) or a similar application code for secure password storage..

To enforce the policy constraints, write this logic in application code.

Comment: So, can I make a password contain only 2 numbers and 5 letters with CHECK CONTRAINTS?

Comment: No, once its hashed the password won't be in clear text. Hence "write this logic in application code" for enforcing password policy.